# How can I refactor a d3 pie to accept more or less data points?

Tags: d3.js

I have [a project](https://jsfiddle.net/jwaldner/zmt165ae/) that almost works the way I want. When a smaller dataset is added, slices are removed. It fails when a larger dataset is added. The space for the arc is added but no label or color is added for it.

This is my `enter()` code:

```
newArcs.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("stroke", "white")
.attr("stroke-width", 0.8)
.attr("fill", function(d, i) {
  return color(i);
})
.attr("d", arc);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In debugging I noticed that the dataset on the initial load is an array and on the update it is an object.  not sure why or if it matters.  The update is triggered on an interval.  I test with two datasets of different lengths...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the code such that it works now:

```js
// Tween Function
var arcTween = function(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this.current || {}, a);
  this.current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
};
// Setup all the constants
var duration = 500;
var width = 500
var height = 300
var radius = Math.floor(Math.min(width / 2, height / 2) * 0.9);
var colors = ["#d62728", "#ff9900", "#004963", "#3497D3"];

// Test Data
var d2 = [{
  label: 'apples',
  value: 20
}, {
  label: 'oranges',
  value: 50
}, {
  label: 'pears',
  value: 100
}];

var d1 = [{
  label: 'apples',
  value: 100
}, {
  label: 'oranges',
  value: 20
}, {
  label: 'pears',
  value: 20
}, {
  label: 'grapes',
  value: 20
}];

// Set the initial data
var data = d1

var updateChart = function(dataset) {
  arcs = arcs.data(donut(dataset), function(d) { return d.data.label });

  arcs.exit().remove();

  arcs.enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .attr("stroke-width", 0.8)
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      return color(i);
    })
    .attr("d", arc);

  arcs.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween);

  sliceLabel = sliceLabel.data(donut(dataset), function(d) { return d.data.label });

  sliceLabel.exit().remove();

  sliceLabel.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "arcLabel")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (arc.centroid(d)) + ")";
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
      if (d.value === 0) {
        return 1e-6;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.label;
    });


  sliceLabel.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (arc.centroid(d)) + ")";
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
      if (d.value === 0) {
        return 1e-6;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    });

};

var color = d3.scale.category20();
var donut = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * .4)
  .outerRadius(radius);
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var arc_grp = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "arcGrp")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height / 2) + ")");
var label_group = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "lblGroup")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height / 2) + ")");

var arcs = arc_grp.selectAll("path");
var sliceLabel = label_group.selectAll("text");

updateChart(data);


// returns random integer between min and max number
function getRand() {
  var min = 1,
    max = 2;

  var res = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  //console.log(res);
  return res;
}


// Update the data
setInterval(function(model) {
  var r = getRand();
  return updateChart(r == 1 ? d1 : d2);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you will laugh but I just got it working! I think I like your way better!  Thanks so much!!

Comment: it works, my visual studio shows as syntax error with:  var updateChart = function(dataset) {
            arcs = arcs.data(donut(dataset), d => d.data.label); on the => not sure what the intent is with the code...

Comment: @keepTrackOfYourStack these are es6 arrow functions you can replace them with regular functions. Turn `() => ...` to `function() {...}`

Comment: @keepTrackOfYourStack I've updated my answer such that it doesn't use ES6 arrow functions.

Comment: sorry theDude! I thought i clicked the bounty  button days ago!! i did now. Thank you